# Question about hide button on click or show

Tags: actionscript-3, button, adobe-animate

How can I force my button to hide or show or change appearance on click?
I use actionscript3 by adobe animate.
Mouse over and mouse down are working. But on release I see mouse up image.
Note: I shouldn't have more than one scene because all of my buttons are in one scene. anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: **(1)** Try setting `.alpha` property of the button. On your function for handling mouse Click event, you set like example `myButton.alpha = 0;` to make it hidden (is not visible but is still clickable). You might want to use an **If/Else** to control visibility **On** (=1) or **Off** (=0). **(2)** _"Change appearance"_ depends on your code setup. Maybe you  have a MovieClip with Mouse listener to act as a button so on mouse "Over" you tell Mclip to go to frame 2 and on "Click" you tell it to go to frame 3 etc. Or instead maybe you made your button by code so edit its `.graphics` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.ui.*;


    dynamic public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var MyButton:MovieClip;
        public var HideMouseTimer:Timer;
        
        public function Main()
        {
            this.MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMyButton);
            
            this.HideMouseTimer = new Timer(5000, 1);
            this.HideMouseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, this.HideMouseTimerEvent);
            setInterval(this.HideMouse, 100);
        }

        public function HideMouseTimerEvent(event:TimerEvent) : void
        {
            Mouse.hide();
            this.MyButton.visible = false;
        }// end function

        public function HideMouse() : void
        {
            if (this.mouseXprev == mouseX && this.mouseYprev == mouseY)
            {
                this.HideMouseTimer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                Mouse.show();
                this.MyButton.visible = true;
                this.HideMouseTimer.reset();
            }
            this.mouseXprev = mouseX;
            this.mouseYprev = mouseY;
        }// end function

        public function onMyButton (event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace ("Pressed MyButton");
        }
    } //end Class Main
    
} //end Package
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).